# Sencha Touch 2 - How to run a function after a view is loaded?

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, touch, extjs

I have a view in Sencha Touch which I populate via the initialize function. Here's the code:

```
Ext.define("Pycsell.view.Home", {
    extend: "Ext.form.Panel",
    requires: "Ext.form.FieldSet",
    alias: "widget.homepage",
    config:{
        scrollable: false,
        cls: 'splash_screen',
        layout: 'vbox'
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        var fb_login = {
            xtype: 'button',
            cls: 'fb_login_button'
        };

        var tradreg = {
            xtype: 'button',
            cls: 'tradreg_button'
        };

        var tradlog = {
            xtype: 'button',
            cls: 'tradlog_button'
        };

        var logo_container = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            cls: 'logo_container',
            width: '90%',
            flex: 4,
        });

        var button_container = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            cls: 'splash_content',
            items: [fb_login, tradreg, tradlog],
            flex: 2,
        });


        this.add([
            logo_container,
            button_container
        ]);
        this.setButtonSizes();

    },//End init

    setButtonSizes: function() {
        console.log('Width is:' + $('.fb_login_button').width());
        console.log('Old height is:' + $('.fb_login_button').height());
        var height = $('.fb_login_button').width()*0.29;
        $('.fb_login_button').height(height);
        console.log('New height is:' + $('.fb_login_button').height());
    }
});
```

Now, the setButtonSizes function does fire, but all the values are null, leading me to believe that the items haven't actually been initialized at the time it's called. How would I go about doing this properly so that the values are actually set? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason you use both jQuery and Sencha Touch ?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how else I'd get a handle on the component otherwise.

Comment: You can use Ext.getCmp('ID'); OR Ext.ComponentQuery.query('XTYPE') OR Ext.DomQuery.select('SELECTOR');

Comment: this question is in android field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be notoriously tricky to get right.  The problem is that your function is probably being called before the component is rendered.  I haven't done any work with Sencha Touch 2, but it looks like using the painted event should help.  Something like this:

```
Ext.define("Pycsell.view.Home", {
 extend: "Ext.form.Panel",
 requires: "Ext.form.FieldSet",
 alias: "widget.homepage",
 config:{
     scrollable: false,
     cls: 'splash_screen',
     layout: 'vbox'
 },
  initialize: function () {
     this.callParent(arguments);
      var fb_login = {
         xtype: 'button',
         cls: 'fb_login_button'
     };
      var tradreg = {
         xtype: 'button',
         cls: 'tradreg_button'
     };
      var tradlog = {
         xtype: 'button',
         cls: 'tradlog_button'
     };
      var logo_container = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
         cls: 'logo_container',
         width: '90%',
         flex: 4,
     });
      var button_container = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
         cls: 'splash_content',
         items: [fb_login, tradreg, tradlog],
         flex: 2,
     });
       this.add([
         logo_container,
         button_container
     ]);
     /* Attaches a listener to the component that will be fired after the
     component is rendered or shown. */
     this.on('painted', this.setButtonSizes);
  },//End init
  setButtonSizes: function() {
     console.log('Width is:' + $('.fb_login_button').width());
     console.log('Old height is:' + $('.fb_login_button').height());
     var height = $('.fb_login_button').width()*0.29;      
     $('.fb_login_button').height(height);
     console.log('New height is:' + $('.fb_login_button').height());
 }
});
```

Depending on quite what you're trying to accomplish, this may fire the event too many times (looks like it fires every time the component is shown too).  So you may have to adjust setButtonSizes to compensate.

Comment: Gonna try it in a bit, sounds like that's the right one. What I'm trying to accomplish is resize the buttons on the screen dynamically so they adhere to a % size of the screen, rather than fixed px values.